# XML Schema: Element with attributes containing values from other attributes

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Not sure this is possible with XSD, but still the question is here.

So I have the following code in my xml:

```
<formats>
    <format name="TableText">
        <item name="halign">left</item>

    </format>
</formats>


<styles>
    <style name="Style">
        <item name="format">TableText</item>
    </style>
</styles>
```

What I want to achieve is that when the user starts typing content of a format (`<item name="format">TableText</item>`), he would only be able to enter what he had in a name attribute of a format tag (`<format name="TableText">`)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to define a constraint (using key/keyref) that the value of `style/item` must be a value that's present in `format/item`, but whether any XML editing tool is able to use such a constraint to drive syntax-directed editing is another question.

Comment: could you please me a hint or better a code snippet on how to achieve that? IDE is out of scope in this question.

Comment: you mean you want help in writing the schema, or you want help in writing the syntax-directed editor that makes use of the schema?